# Add VirtoCommerce Theme

Tags: themes, virtocommerce

I am trying out VirtoCommerce for a work project. I am impressed with all the technologies being used. However the community seems rather small.
In VirtoCommerce, what file should I choose to add a theme?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can take any of the existing themes as a starting point to creating your own. You can also download skeleton theme, that contains all the basic controls.

Comment: thanks seems that the one of the module was bugging when i installed it for some reason. reinstalled it now it works.